# Shared pointer confusion

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently learning the smart pointers and I got a bit confused. Why the shared pointer does not print the memory address that stores as raw pointer neither with simple print nor with get() ?

```
int x = 100;
int* y = &x;
std::cout<<&x<<std::endl;
std::cout<<y<<std::endl;

std::shared_ptr<int> x2 = std::make_shared<int>(x);
std::cout<<x2.get()<<std::endl


0x7ffe965e20b4                                                                                                       
0x7ffe965e20b4                                                                                                       
**0x2176c30**  so why this value is for both x2.get() and x2 ?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`x2` does not point to the same location as `x`.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> x2 = std::make_shared<int>(x);
```

This lines creates a new pointer to int and initializes it with the value that `x` has.

So they only thing they have in common at this point is the fact that both the pointers `x` and `x2` points to an `int` with the value 100. Still 2 different `int`s though.

Comment: thank for response, it's not clear for me.. the shared pointer x2 how points to resource x, if it does not store its memory address ? I would like to see a picture with all objects .. to get straight with this

Comment: It doesn't point to resource x. That's the whole point. It's a completely separate `int`. It's just initialized with the same value.

Comment: so it clones the resource x and creates a new resource to point at ?

Comment: @DanFlick: That's what `make_shared` *does*. That's why it starts with "make".

Comment: It's not clear for me how the shared_pointer gets the memory address that will store ..

Comment: @NicolBolas, if the shared pointer it's created with new instead of make_shared the result is same, please clarify this think for me, a new resource is created from x and the shared pointer stores the new resource memory address or what happens? from where the shared pointer gets the value that will store ?

Comment: @DanFlick: "*if the shared pointer it's created with new instead of make_shared the result is same*" Yes, because in both cases you are allocating a new object. If you want to adopt an existing allocation, you *don't use `new`*. And when I say "existing allocation", I don't mean "address of a stack variable."

Comment: How can be adopted an exisiting allocation? as I understand so far a shared pointer is more like a resource owner  than a pointer .. So it;s not clear for me...Please let me know if I'm right..there's a resource x, when will create a shared_pointer for that x than a new resource will be created and the shared_pointer will be the owner of that.. so there's no further relation between the x and the shared_pointer ?